# Exception AttributeError when starting roscore

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and am going through the tutorials.
I have just attempted to start roscore and am receiving the following error:

```
*auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [3719]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311/
setting /run_id to 897134ae-b183-11e1-9fcb-00269ed0509d
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3732]
started core service [/rosout]*
```

After this last line, it seems that the process hangs. I can input new commands but no output is displayed.

I also ran these commands before running the roscore command:

```
$ export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36056/exception-attributeerror-when-starting-roscore/) by [sl0w](https://answers.ros.org/users/2556/sl0w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6 on 2012-06-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-08**:
Despite the annoying error message, there is nothing apparently wrong here. Roscore is running, so you need to open another terminal window for other commands to have an immediate effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to be the same as [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/34304/exception-attributeerror-when-starting-roscore/) and should be harmless.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0